# Eclipse Java EE debug crashes

Tags: eclipse, debugging, crash, timeoutexception

I keep getting an error of `org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException while waiting for packet -- occurred creating step request`.

When that happens I need to restart Eclipse and start all over which is very unproductive.

I tried changing the Timeout settings in options but that didn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: And this happens when? When you debug a certain app?

Comment: this happens when I debug any JEE application.  I step through the code and that works fine for a while, but after a couple of minutes I get this error, which many times requires me to restart Eclipse and start all over.

Comment: According to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=83937), the timeout think has been fixed a while ago. What version of Eclipse are you using again?

Comment: I believe that I have the most current version:  
Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800