# org eclipse(3.8) jdi timeoutexception: error occured while waiting for packet xxx. occured creating a step request

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

while debugging my program within which I am synchronizing threads, an error message pops up on the sleeping instruction. does anyone know how to fix those kind of problem. I have the feeling that this might be because the thread might sleeping and requested at the same time. but this only occurs when debugging which means that my assumption is wrong .Below is a sample of the code where the sleep instruction is.

```
private static void testAsync(byte []data){

sendAsync(data);
try{
Thread.sleep(5000);// the error occurs here when sleeping
}catch(InterruptedException){}

}
```

this is the error message: org eclipse jdi timeoutexception: error occured while waiting for packet xxx. occured creating a step request.
I am  having eclipse 3.8
the best answer I got is at [Eclipse Java EE debug crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832879/eclipse-java-ee-debug-crashes) but it does not give me much info since there is not strict answer and the situations are also different

Comment: Sounds like it might be this Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=94452

Comment: ok but it was said to have been fixed

Comment: Not 94452 which is still open and was updated recently.